# Extremely Slow SmtpClient Using Office 365

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I'm working on MVC5 website. This website contains "contact us" form where user can contact website support.

The problem is that the **SendMailAsync takes at least 10-13 seconds to complete** (no attachments) and while this process is running, user is stuck and waiting for the response from the server - whether the email was sent successfully or not.

This is my current ActionResult method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(MessageModel Model)
{
    //...
    await SendMessage(Model);
    //...
    return View();
}
```

And this is my method responsible for sending the email:

```
private async Task SendMessage(MessageModel Model)
{
    var Message = new MailMessage();
    Message.From = ...;
    Message.To.Add(...);
    Message.Subject = ...;
    Message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
    Client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    Client.Credentials = ...;
    Client.Port = 587;
    Client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    Client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    Client.EnableSsl = true;

    await Client.SendMailAsync(Message);
}
```

**Are there any faster working alternatives?** I could run it like this:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMessage(Model));
```

The website would not be "stuck" for 13 seconds and response would be instantaneous, however, I would not be able too provide the user with information whether the email was sent successfully or not.

Comment: There could be any number of causes for this. Your best bet is to install Wireshark and inspect the packets being sent to and from the SMTP server. The .NET code will not continue until the mail server responds with "Successfully queued for delivery". Artificial delays can be set on when that response is sent, which may be worth looking into.

Comment: Additionally, creating a new thread to send the email is *not* the same thing as backgrounding. The action will still not return until the work is completed. All you're doing is adding overhead, which is why creating new threads in web application is generally discouraged.

Comment: Yes, if responsiveness is important, I would do it as a "fire and forget" task - you're on the right track with your last snippet, but if you await it, I think it will defeat the purpose.  For notification, you may be able to implement an AJAX timer that checks the server periodically to see if you have an update to display and then shows the user a message - I haven't done a ton of that type of work, but there are tutorials out there such as this: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e644e9a7-f1ec-41d1-ad19-5cda53b6e9cf.aspx

Comment: For a fire and forget situation you can just remove the `await` keyword in your last code line: simply call `Client.SendMailAsync(Message);`. And yes, this way you won't get a success message back, but what you implemented doesn't allow for failures yet anyway.

Comment: For the testing's sake, as it is unclear what costs the time (possibly your called service), you could change your last code line to `await Client.SendMailAsync(Message).ConfigureAwait(false);`. This it could be faster if something blocks your local thread.

Comment: .ConfigureAwait(false); Didn't do anything, I think I'll go with my last example and hope for the best. Also, sorry for the wrong terminology.

Comment: my website using 365 smtp takes 15 sec per mail, terrible

Answer (score 1):

We ran into similar problems recently for an event registration, 4-5 sec for each email, and we needed to send multiple with different content. The client's IT person was able to get a .protection.outlook.com:25 server accepting non ssl traffic running on the same domain and it took the time to 1-1.5 sec. Which was fast enough for the client with some UI to show we were processing. We also tried a local server and it was only about 100ms, but they didn't want to have that email service running on their DC.

I can't speak to the specifics of the setup for this .protection.outlook.com server since I wasn't involved, but it may be something to look into if you don't want to rely on async.